# How to override Bootstrap's Panel heading background color?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Panel from `Bootstrap` however for the heading I want to use my own background color for the heading. When I don't put `panel-heading` class for the `div`, the layout gets screwed. So I thought I should keep `panel-heading` but then find a way to override the background color. So I decided to create a custom css class and use `background-color` and then add it to the div with `panel-heading`. But this didn't make any effect.

Any idea how to override the heading color of the panel?

Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading custom_class" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 55):

This should work:

```
.panel > .panel-heading {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;

}
```

Comment: Just to explicitly help people who stumble in here, you can't set the background-color unless you remove the background-image.

Comment: The background-image covers the background-color, so even though you have set the background-color, you cannot see it.

Answer (score 39):

You can create a custom class for your panel heading. Using this css class you can style the panel heading. I have a simple Fiddle for this.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-custom">
       <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       Panel content
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading-custom {
background: #ff0000; color: #fff; }
```

Demo Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/t1Lq966k/

Comment: This is the only one that worked, if you don't want to override all panel headings, only the custom one.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add your own custom classes, just directly target the bootstrap contextual class. See my answer.

Comment: Best answer. You can use `.panel-heading-custom` class almost as you would an `info` class on headings

Answer (score 14):

How about creating your own Custom Panel class? That way you won't have to worry about overriding Bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-custom-horrible-red">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-custom-horrible-red {
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
.panel-custom-horrible-red > .panel-heading {
    background: #ff0000; 
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/x05f4crg/1/

Comment: You don't need to either create your own classes OR override bootstrap. Just use contextual css to target what you want. See my answer on how to do that, it's easy.

Comment: @rmcsharry Using contextual css _is_ overriding bootstrap styles. Creating your own custom panel variation is a better practice as you then you don't have to "fight" or override any bootstrap styles. It gives you better control.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so the correct phrase is "You don't need to create your own classes to override bootstrap."  But since Bootstrap provides these contextual classes, you can target them, I don't feel any fight in doing that - especially if I want all my panels to use that style, which I usually do.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap sometimes uses contextual class constructs. Those are what you should target to change styling.

You don't need to create your own custom class as suggested in the answer from Kiran Varti.

So you only need:

CSS:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background: #black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
```

Explanation [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/change-background-color-of-panelheading-bootstrap). Also see contextual class section [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.asp).

To match navbar-inverse use #222. Panel-inverse was [requested](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16128) in V3, but rejected due to larger priorities.

You can change the foreground color in that heading override or you can do it separately for panel titles. Depends what you are trying to achieve.

```
.panel-title {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to change the color is remove the default class and replace , in the panel using the classes of bootstrap.

example:

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried using custom panel class but it didn't work. So for those who are struggling just like me, you can use `inline CSS` and it works fine for me.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="background-image:none;background: #a4c6ff;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an id attribute to the panel. Like this

`<div class="panel-heading" id="mypanelId">Hello world </div>`

> Then in your custom CSS file:

```
#mypanelId{
    background-image: none;
    background: rgba(22, 20, 100, 0.8);
    color: white;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

am assuming custom_class to be your class to override heading color of the panel.
just add !important to it or add inline styles or a id and  add styles as they will have more specificity over class added styles.

- with !important

  .custom_class{
     background-color: red !important;
  }
- with !important
- with ID :

  #custom_id{
         background-color: red;
      }

-with inline styles :

```
<div id="custom_id" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading custom_class" style="background-color:red">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @AlexTwain can u make a fiddle for it , it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel-default >.panel-heading
{
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

This is what worked for me to change the color to white.

Answer (score -3):

Just check the bootstrap.
CSS and search for the class panel-heading and copy the default code.

Copy the default CSS to your personal CSS but vive it a diference classname like my-panel-header for example.

Edit the css Code from the new clones class created.

Answer (score -3):

use this :

```
.panel-heading {
    background-color: #ececb0 !important;
}
```