# Aligning Panels in center and changing their header and body colors with bootstrap and css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this website i am designing for purpose of a school project and I wanted to use the accordion panels I found this code on w3schools but I want to change the look and the positioning of it a little bit. this is what I've gotten so far:
[image]

but I want these accordion panels to align to the center of the website and I want to change the color of their headers to the same color of the navbar, possibly change their body color. Perhaps also the font color if necessary to see the text. Also the items in mij Navbar are centered but also a bit off, How do I adjust them to be right in the middle ? this is the .css code i have for navbar items so far:

```
  #myNavbar {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: post your html code or create jsfiddle

Comment: here's the https://jsfiddle.net/Tom_EMK/mhmu7xcf/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align the accordion panels to the center of the page you can make use of the bootstrap grid system. The bootstrap grid system is a powerfull way to make pages responsive.

Check out the  [bootstrap page - grid option](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options.). It takes a bit of time to get your head around it but i can save you much time in the future.
There are also several tutorials on youtube about the usage of the grid system.

Comment: Wow thanks, I've read into this before but though this would be quite useless if you're not using the other grid div elements but I think I got them centered somewhat, now I just want to know if this is applicable to the navbar item? Also, how do I change the color of these accordion panels?

Comment: That question has been asked before on stackoverflow. Try to check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505033/how-to-override-bootstraps-panel-heading-background-color

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions about the grid system and i'll be happy to try to help you with it.

Comment: fair enough, but I still have a remaining white border around the colored in heading part, how do I make that disappear?

Comment: updated: https://jsfiddle.net/Tom_EMK/mhmu7xcf/16/ nvm the colors just assume I'm colorblind xD

Comment: in your css you should add the following lines:

".panel-group .panel {
    border:none;
}"

This border is default in bootstrap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100423/discussion-between-lars-and-tom-kustermans).